# React Native 0.61.5/0.63.3 Expo 38/39 Android Cannot connect to development server

Tags: android, react-native, expo

Yes I've tried the wifi (setting the ip and port) and the adb reverse tcp method and the clear text setting in AndroidManifest.xml

Its really odd because I can adb shell onto the device and curl to the development server which works and shows up in the metro terminal, however when I start the app on the device it doesn't even try to connect.

Happened on both React Native 0.61.5/0.63.3 Expo 38/39 using Android 10 and Mac Big Sur

Comment: What happen when you enter your mac ip address like ```http://XXX.XXX.XX.XXX:19000/``` in the browser?

Comment: React Native packager is running.
Visit documentation

 is what gets displayed when I go to the url, on both the android and Mac

Comment: sorry just to add, I use port 8081, 19000 isnt being used